# Accessing internal class through reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, internal

Currently I wanted to do a UT coverage for which 100% function coverage is needed.
I have a Public Class called FunctionParser.cs in my application and this internally uses an internal class called Autocomplete provided by Third party. Now the problem is there are few functionalities that lie within the AutoComplete Class which are untested . Therefore in order to do the coverage for this internal class named "AutoComplete" am trying to use reflection but nothing works for me can some one say me how can I use reflection to access this internal class for test purpose.

Note : I cannot modify the AutoComplete.CS which is an internal class provided by 3rd party, so other than using •Get [InternalsVisibleTo] . please suggest anything else that could work without modifying the third party class

Comment: You should be able to use reflection on internals. Show us what you've tried already.

Comment: What do you mean "nothing works". Thats like going to the doctor and simply saying "I am not feeling well"!

Answer (score 4):

```
var innerType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                .Where(t => t.DeclaringType == typeof(Outer))
                .First(t => t.Name == "Inner");

var innerObject = Activator.CreateInstance(innerType);
innerType.GetMethod("InnerTest", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
         .Invoke(innerObject, new object[] { });
```

--

```
public class Outer
{
    class Inner
    {
        internal void InnerTest()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi , At first thanks to everyone for the response . Answer 1 : I would like to mention that its not "third party code" , it is basically our own code but we do not want to make any modification to it thats the reason i mentioned it as 3rd party.                                                               Answer 2 : Its not that my constructor is internal my class itself is Internal i.e in the class declaration itself its marked internal.

Comment: Am sorry i just observed that the InnerTest is not a constructor , would test this and get back

Answer (score 3):

You are not supposed to unit test code provided by third party. If your code is dependent on external code, then mock the behavior of that code. The external library may need encapsulation in additional class that implements special interface for example. Than inject that interface into your code for example in constructor. In the unit tests you will inject mocked implementation.